# How to write this line better in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having simple if statment and I want to verify that the returns having default value,
if yes put it on some variable,for me it look little bit ugly(to use the statement twice), there is shorter/nicer way to write it in JS?

```
    if (this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal) {
        var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal;
```

Comment: What falsy value could it have?

Comment: You can directly assign it i.e."var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal;". If the returns have default value then you will get the value in 'defValue' variable otherwise it's value will be null. So no need to use the whole statment twice. You can also put the variable in 'if condition'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me. If the value is undefined then you should define the variable like so:

```
if(typeof something === 'undefined')
 var something = 'something';
```

But in your case the value is already testing if this exists then define the variable, so doesn't make any sense. So, you just use the variable there:

```
var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal;
```

You may also check if not to use if not defined like so:

```
var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal || 'undefined';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign it i.e.

```
var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal;
```

If the returns have default value then you will get the value in 'defValue' variable otherwise it's value will be null. So no need to use the whole statment twice. You can also put the variable in 'if condition'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal || 0;
```

---

If there is anything in `this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal` then assign the value of it or set the value to `0` which is known as boolean `false` in javascript.

`0` will only be assigned when `this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal` results in `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks but what does it mean "no value",can you please provide some explanation ?

Comment: "no value" will be returned if this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal is null, false,0 etc

Comment: it just fills the value if `this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal` returns nothing which results in `undefind/null/false/0` there might be possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `||` it?

```
var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal || false; // or whatever alternative you want it to be?
```

Comment: Because that does a different thing?

Comment: It depends what you want the alternative to be. If it is `undefined`, then just do `var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal'`, but if you want some "else" value, then this is short.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal;
if (defValue) {
     …
} // else { // only if you depend on the `undefined` value:
//     defValue = undefined;
// }
```

Alternatively, if there is no code in the if-statement, you could do

```
var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal || undefined;
```

or, if you'd expect `.defVal` to be undefined anyway as the possibly falsy value (and you don't want to test for `0`, `""`, `false`, `null`), just

```
var defValue = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

in general, and especially if you use some kind of function to get a value, it's better to place it in a local var and then check that (continue work with it. Be mindful about the possible values though. If the returnValue can be legitimately 0, then you have to check against null and undefined, because 0 evaluates to false.

```
// some possible expensive operation you only want to do once
var myReturnVal = this._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal;
if (myReturnVal) {
    var defValue = myReturnVal;
    // do more stuff
} else {
   // do other stuff
}
```

That being said you can just assign it anyway, as long as that value is not an object with own functions. because trying something as the following will break your program.

```
// if myREturnValue is undefined/null, this will crash
myReturnVal.doSomething()
```

Answer (score -1):

One common way to make if statements clearer is to move the check itself to a method, like this. That way you make it more readable and extendable without losing focus while reading the code. In my opionon this looks better. (Just the idea, not correct implementetion, you need to check for null and get the correct value as well from getDefaultValue(this)).

```
if(returnsDefaultValue(this))
    vardefValue = getDefaultValue(this);


function returnsDefaultValue(self){
    return self._oIn._mMet[sM].returns.defVal ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, don't see why I get downvote. Would be nice with a comment. One of the questions was "for me it look little bit ugly(to use the statement twice)". This is a suggestion to make the code cleaner and clearer.